# __eq__ implementation for hashing of multiple types

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have a custom class which I want to be able to use as a key in a dictionary. So, I need to define the `__eq__` function. In my case, this is simple:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
```

Here `other` needs to be basically of the same type and I am comparing some member variables. However, the `name` is just a string and what I was thinking was that the user could also check by specifying a string. To make it concrete, here is what I had in mind:

```
class Hashable(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.other_att = dict()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

# Example usage
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict()
h = Hashable("Name")
c[h] = list()
if h in c:
    print ("Yes!")   # This is fine...
```

However, also want to do:

```
if 'Name' in c:
```

Can I implement many `__eq__` functions or do I need to check for the type of `other` in the equality function. What is a pythonic an hopefully efficient way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to just have the names as the keys and make the objects the names come from part of the value.

Comment: Also: don't forget to implement `__ne__`, because it's not provided for you on Python 2, and keep in mind that you're Officially Supposed To return `NotImplemented` for comparisons against objects your type doesn't handle instead of raising an `AttributeError` or returning `False` (to give the other side a chance to define what the comparison means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and provide the default as `other` in case `other` has no attribute `name` e.g. it's a string:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.name == getattr(other, 'name', other)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `try-except`, because sometimes it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return self.name == other.name
    except AttributeError:
        return self.name == other
```